# What's the best way to share a watched property across different components in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have this watched property called cases:

```
cases: {
  handler: function () {
    let vc = this
    if (vc.areCasesValid()) {
      console.log('schema-cases#handler - casesValid', vc.cases)
      vc.setApiModelFromView()
      vc.$emit('valid', vc.apiModel)
      return true
    }
    else {
      console.log('template-heuristic-cases#handler - casesInvalid', vc.cases)
      vc.$emit('invalid')
      return false
    }
  },
  deep: true
},
```

All validation steps are currently inside the `areCasesValid`function, but I want to improve the usability of the application and that process involves putting the different validation steps into different components.

Taking that into account, what's the easiest (not necessarily the most elegant) way to observe the different changes that `cases` goes through in different components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep it simple and don't want to use state management like vuex, you can use an event bus:

Your event bus:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
export const EventBus = new Vue();
```

Your component that emits the event:

```
<template>
  <div class="pleeease-click-me" @click="emitGlobalClickEvent()"></div>
</template>

<script>
// Import the EventBus we just created.
import { EventBus } from './event-bus.js';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      clickCount: 0
    }
  },

  methods: {
    emitGlobalClickEvent() {
      this.clickCount++;
      // Send the event on a channel (i-got-clicked) with a payload (the click count.)
      EventBus.$emit('i-got-clicked', this.clickCount);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Your component that receives the event:

```
// Import the EventBus.
import { EventBus } from './event-bus.js';

// Listen for the i-got-clicked event and its payload.
EventBus.$on('i-got-clicked', clickCount => {
  console.log(`Oh, that's nice. It's gotten ${clickCount} clicks! :)`)
});
```

Full example and more explanation can be found here: https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/

Comment: I am apparently emitting the event correctly but it's not being listened correctly. I added the listening function inside the mounted function. Where should the listening function be placed?

Comment: Just to be clear: It's printing console.log(`Oh, that's nice. It's gotten ${clickCount} clicks! :)`) but the changes aren't taking effect in the interface